# Book about an asteroid passing really close to Earth and how the people thought they were going to die, so they made the last day on Earth party

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the book last year, it is written in different perspectives, basically everyone thinks the meteor is going to hit the Earth, and they make a the end of the world party.

Comment: I'm thinking that this probably is **not** *The Big Eye* by Max Ehrlich. I don't remember that one having lots of different perspectives in it, and I don't think the human race was throwing a huge party right before they all expected to die. But do you remember anything about the major characters in the book that might help pin it down? (I have read other stories where everybody believes the end of the world is coming . . .)

Comment: Maybe something by Tim Powers.

Comment: Hello Day, welcome to [fantasy.se] and thank you for your question. When you say "last year", you mean 2017, right? Also, please take a look at [this guide to asking identification requests](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561). If that jogs your memory, you can [edit] your question to add details. Lastly, may I invite you to take the [tour]?

Comment: You sure it's a book? It might be a common trope but I read a comic last year with this same plot...

Comment: Honorable mention to *Comet in Moominland* for a slightly similar theme.

Comment: Sounds somewhat like the book Nemesis, I guess? Never read it, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [*We All Looked Up*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18392459-we-all-looked-up) (2015) by Tommy Wallach. It follows...I think 5 teenagers? As they approach the end of the world. They then organise an 'end of the world' party which they post about online so that people from all over come to see the end through.

> Before the asteroid we let ourselves be defined by labels:
>   The athlete, the outcast, the slacker, the overachiever.
>
> But then we all looked up and everything changed.
>
> They said it would be here in two months. That gave us two months to leave our labels behind. Two months to become something bigger than what we'd been, something that would last even after the end.
>
> Two months to really live.